# react-native-fbsdk-next Android Login Button results in oAuth error

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk-next and followed all steps to set up Android/iOS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk-next)

iOS works perfectly.

On android i receive the following redirect right after user clicks the LoginButton provided by the the fb sdk:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<LoginButton
            onLoginFinished={getOnLoginFinished()}
            onLogoutFinished={() => {
              console.log('logout.');
            }}
/>
```

```
  function getOnLoginFinished() {
    return async (error, result) => {
      let userAccessToken;
      LoginManager.setLoginBehavior('native_with_fallback');
      if (error) {
        console.log('login has error: ' + result.error);
      } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        console.log('login is cancelled.');
      } else {
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
          .then(data => {
            setUserAccessToken(data.accessToken.toString());
            console.log(data.accessToken.toString());
            console.log(result.grantedPermissions);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(`Get current access token, err ${err}`);
          });
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Expected deprecation, more detail here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews

Along with potential solution.